# Android Textview text as a tag

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm trying to set the width of the LinearLayout depending on the length of the text in it (like a tag), so the longer the text the bigger the layout. I don't want the text on another line;

[image: Android Tag]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="asdsadsaddsadsadasdasdadasd" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

so I tried this for you, and layout expands or shrinks the as size of textview

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is the following:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="asdsadsaddsadsadasdasdadasd" />
```